# Can't reproduce error with .NET

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, namespaces

I am pretty sure each of us might have seen this problem at some point I do see it often but can't reproduce it. Here is the problem:

When sometimes we name the Namespace and Class with the same exact name then compiler sometimes gets confused and doesn't know if we are referring to the class or the assembly and does not resolve the class when we try to refer to it in our application.

That happened to me once. However, It does not always happen to me. ALso, none of my colleagues are facing the problem. SO when I changed the class name to differentiate from the namespace then they argued saying it its OK to have the same Namespace name and class name.

I know that it is not OK and it will throw reference errors at some point but do not have any proof because I can not reproduce the same error. Any idea how can I reproduce this?

Comment: If you can't reproduce it, how can you be sure it is an issue?

Comment: As I said, it does not always create an issue. VS has been inconsistent in reporting it as an issue: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one.aspx

Comment: Is it even worthwhile to recreate the issue? Why not have better name for the class? Not having that often raises questions about the existence of that class.It could also be trying to do too many things violating single responsibility principle. Besides that here's some guidelines on naming http://10rem.net/articles/net-naming-conventions-and-programming-standards---best-practices

Answer (score 1):

In short, yes, VS will get a conflict if you have ambiguous classes. Assume you have a module A, which refers to modules B and C. Module B contains a class My.Namespace.AwesomeClass. Module C also contains another class called My.Namespace.AwesomeClass.

Since A refers to both B and C, you cannot expect the compiler to automatically distinguish between your usages. So it will give you an error. Best to avoid this situation by giving unique names.

---

There are a few basic guidelines for naming your creations:

The namespace and class name together uniquely describe your class. Regardless of VS errors, it is always a good idea to have clear unambiguous names for all your constructs.

The namespace uniquely defines:

1. Your organization
2. Your project
3. Your module and submodule

Your class name defines the functionality.

So it should be very difficult to get conflicts in naming as long as you have well-factored functionality.